# How to copy lines from 4th till 11th and paste it from 15th till 22th line in ex mode?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, normal-mode, ex-mode

To move cursor on the 4th line,toggle into normal mode,input `8yy`.
To move cursor to 15th line,and toggle into normal mode,press `p` .

Now the lines from 4th till 11th was pasted from 15th  till  22th line.

Can all the steps can be repalced with a command in ex mode?

To make it clear.
primitive file
[image: from]
target file
[image]

How to change primitive file into target file with a command in ex mode?

Comment: Don't post text as screenshots. It takes up a lot of space, you can't copy from it, and it's not even more readable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly but is this what you're looking for?

```
:4,11t 15
```

This will copy lines from 4 to 11 and paste it on line 15.

See `:h co` for more.