# What does :[range]t <line-number> do?

Tags: command-line, cut-copy-paste

I just started playing vimgolf and saw a solution that used this command to select a line and copy it to the line specified. I searched google and vim's documentation and couldn't find anything about what this command is. I was only able to find `:m` which would move lines but this one seems to copy lines and paste them. What does the 't' stand for, is it still "til" because that doesn't make sense to me?

Comment: See this answer, from not so long ago: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/12206/5395

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just needed to include the colon in your help search. It's in there.

> ```
> :[range]co[py] {address}              *:co* *:copy*
>         Copy the lines given by [range] to below the line
>         given by {address}.
>
>                                       *:t*
> :t      Synonym for copy.
> ```

As to *why* it's a synonym for copy, it doesn't say. There may be a history reason but I don't know it.

See [`:help :t`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3At).

Comment: I've read somewhere about "copy **t**o" as the source of synonym

Comment: Well... it looks like I need to learn how to use vim help because that was exactly what I was looking for I just didn't know how to get there. I was looking under the help for cmdline.